# Connect and reconnect LTE modem via systemd

Tags: networking, systemd, usb-modem

I use an USB LTE modem for connecting my Ubuntu 18.04 server to LTE metwork. The modem is 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard.
I wrote a systemd script which starts the connection at boot:

```
[Unit]
Description=Swan LTE connection
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/swan_connect.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

swan_connect.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/echo -e "AT^NDISDUP=1,1,\"internet2\"\r" > /dev/ttyUSB0
/bin/sleep 2
/usr/sbin/netplan apply
```

It works fine but the problem is LTE connection is dropped every 48 hours (or in case of outage) and I need to re-connect and get new IP. I do it currently by a crontab script each minute - if I can't ping an IP, then it will reconnect by these commands:

```
/usr/sbin/netplan apply
/bin/echo -e "AT^NDISDUP=1,0,\"internet2\"\r" > /dev/ttyUSB0
/bin/sleep 2
/bin/echo -e "AT^NDISDUP=1,1,\"internet2\"\r" > /dev/ttyUSB0
/bin/sleep 2
/usr/sbin/netplan apply
```

Again - it works fine but I was just thinking whether there would not be a systemd version of this re/connecting. **Is it possible to make a systemd script in a way systemd would re-connect the LTE connection if dropped?**

Answer (score 0):

`systemd` offers a number of different ways to activate services, including [path-based activation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) to start a service if a file state changes.

There is no built-in facility to react to the network connection being down.

`systemd` does include [systemd timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) as a replacement for Cron, but the end result would the same design:  Perform a check on an interval.